# How do I submit a value by url in php

Tags: php, post, variables, get

I tried this in my php site `<a href=?command=value>click here</a>`

And this to get the value :

```
if(isset($_POST['command'])){

        $command=strip_tags($_GET['command']);
```

Does not seem to work.. Ps. The url have one this value also: `?lang=en_US`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. And also put double quotes around the value of `href` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Try this....this will work...

```
    '<a href="company.php?command=value">click here</a>'
```

this is to get the value from site:

```
   <?php 
  if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])){

    $command=($_GET['command']);
    echo $command;
  }
   ?>
```

the output:   value

Note:Both the codes(php and html) are written in same page(company.php)
we can also write the php code in seperate page. Difference is,the 'isset' function is not needed there.And URL should change.
code will be the following.

```
    '<a href="company.php?command=value">click here</a>'
```

next_php_page.php code:

```
<?php 

  if($_REQUEST['command']){

    $command=($_GET['command']);
    echo $command;
  }
  ?>
```